Gradle DSL: getting property value when registering task
I'm trying something pretty simple I would say
I create a custom task named UnitTestTask and I want to execute some tasks depending of a property set in an external build.gradle.kts but when accessing the property, it is always null
Here is the declaration:
abstract class UnitTestTask : DefaultTask() {

    @get:Input
    @get:Optional
    abstract val variantsToExclude: ListProperty<String>
}

The registration in my Convention which extends of Plugin<Project>:
    override fun apply(project: Project) {

        project.tasks.register<UnitTestTask>(UNIT_TEST_TASK_NAME) {
                val variants = variantsToExclude.orNull
                // variants is always null!!
                val unitTestTasks = project.allprojects
                    .flatMap {
                        it.tasks.matching { task ->
                            if (variants?.isNotEmpty() == true) {
                                task.name.matches("\\b(koverXmlReport\\w+)\\b".toRegex()) &&
                                    variants.none { variant -> task.name.contains(variant) }
                            } else {
                                task.name == KOVER_REPORT_TASK_NAME
                            }
                        }
                    }

                System.out.println("tasks to execute: $unitTestTasks")

                setFinalizedBy(unitTestTasks)
        }
   }

how I'm using the task in my other project build.gradle.kts:
tasks.withType<UnitTestTask> {
        val listToExclude = if (isSnapshot) listOf("Release") else listOf("Debug")
        variantsToExclude.set(listToExclude)
}


The trick was to use a provider so the variantsToExclude is not actually accessed directly but it will only be accessed when the finalizedBy block will be executed so the configuring step will be over and the variantsToExclude will be set.
project.tasks.register<UnitTestTask>(UNIT_TEST_TASK_NAME) {
    // We use the provider so variantsToExclude is not accessed directly
    // it will be accessed in the finalizedBy block so variantsToExclude will be configured
    // otherwise orNull will always return null and the variable won't be configured correctly
    val filteredTasksProvider = project.provider {
        val variants = variantsToExclude.orNull
        project.allprojects.flatMap { project ->
            project.tasks.matching { task ->
                if (variants?.isNotEmpty() == true) {
                    // We don't want to execute the task koverXmlReport
                    // but rather all other koverXmlReportSomething tasks that will be later on filtered
                    // according to the variants
                    task.name.matches("\\b(koverXmlReport\\w+)\\b".toRegex()) &&
                        variants.none { variant -> task.name.contains(variant) }
                } else {
                    task.name == KOVER_REPORT_TASK_NAME
                }
            }
        }
    }

    finalizedBy(filteredTasksProvider)
}

